# create relationship between two tables in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to establish relationship between two tables in rails so
that I can share data between the two tables. However,am not able to
enter data into the operating tables. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
#below are models#
class Location < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :operatings
end

class Operating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
end

##below are my tables##

enable_extension "plpgsql"

create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "country"
  t.string   "supra_region"
  t.string   "region"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end

create_table "operatings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "operating_company_name"
  t.string   "address"
  t.date     "year_formed"
  t.string   "other_operational_countries"
  t.string   "about_company"
  t.string   "current_focus"
  t.string   "incumbent_irm_contractor"
  t.string   "irm_frame_agreements"
  t.text     "estimated_irm_budgets"
  t.integer  "location_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_operatings_on_location_id", using: :btree
end

add_foreign_key "operatings", "locations"

###below is my operating controller###

def create
  @operating = Operating.new(op_company)
  if @operating.save
    flash[:success] = "A recorded has been successfully Saved"
    redirect_to operatings_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

####routes####
resources :offshores,    :index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy
resources :locations,    :index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy
```

Comment: What specific errors/unexpected results are you getting currently?

Comment: I am not able to add data to the operating table at all.

Comment: *am not able to enter data into the operating tables* Do you get any error?

Comment: What is the value of `op_company`?  If `@operating.save` fails, then what is `@operating.errors.messages`? What has the existence of the `Location` model got to do with all this? (Perhaps answering the two questions above will reveal...)

Comment: I **suspect** (but cannot be certain, given the incomplete information provided) that there is a failed validation on the `Operating` model, that has got nothing to do with the `location` association.

Comment: @TomLord the existence of the `Location` is enforced by default in Rails 5. Meaning every [belongs to relationship](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) will ensure the parent exists and if not it will fail to save. (Chances are this has a lot to do with the problem)

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh yeah, good point.... It still would have been glaringly obvious, had the error message been included in the question!! OP, if the `location` is not a mandatory association then you need to use `belongs_to :location, optional: true`. If it is not optional, and/or the error message is different, then you need to provide more details - as explained above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining two tables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981376/joining-two-tables-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Operating < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :location, :optional => true
end
```

belongs_to will check is the association present, you can debug by printing the Operating's errors

```
operating = Operating.create
operating.errors.messages
```