# Joining two tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to link the location and the operating tables so that I can display some data in location table in the operatings views. However, I am stuck and don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 #below are models#
 class Location < ApplicationRecord  
    has_many :operatings
 end

 class Operating < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :location
 end

 ##below are my tables##

 enable_extension "plpgsql"

 create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "supra_region"
    t.string   "region"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
 end

 create_table "operatings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "operating_company_name"
  t.string   "address"
  t.date     "year_formed"
  t.string   "other_operational_countries"
  t.string   "about_company"
  t.string   "current_focus"
  t.string   "incumbent_irm_contractor"
  t.string   "irm_frame_agreements"
  t.text     "estimated_irm_budgets"
  t.integer  "location_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_operatings_on_location_id", using: :btree
 end

 add_foreign_key "operatings", "locations"

 ###below is my operating controller###

  def create
     @operating = Operating.new(op_company)
     if @operating.save
        flash[:success] = "A recorded has been successfully Saved"
        redirect_to operatings_path
     else
        render 'new'
     end
  end

 ####routes####
 resources :offshores,    :index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy
 resources :locations,    :index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Location` and `Operating` models are linked together using `has_many` and `belongs_to`, if you have an `operating` object in your template, you can easily access the attributes of its location:

```
<% @operatings.each do |operating| %>
  <div>The name of its location: <%= operating.location.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

You need to be careful with this though. If you only fetch the operatings from the database, accessing each operating's `location` attribute in that `each` loop will trigger a separate database query for every operating item. This is called an *N+1* query, and it is very inefficient. To fix the problem, make sure to *pre-fetch* the associated location as well when loading operatings using `includes`:

```
# in the controller
@operatings = Operating.all.includes(:location)
```

This way the associated locations of every operating will be fetched using just a single query.

Comment: Please, I am still geting  the error message undefined method `country' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That probably means that the `operating` you are accessing has no associated `location`. If that is okay and expected, you can suppress the error with this: `operating.location.try(:country)`

Comment: Please it does not return any error now but no associated data in the location is retrieved. Also the location_id in the operating table is nil.

Comment: Then that's the problem: if the `location_id` is `nil`, no associated location will be fetched by ActiveRecord. As for why it is `nil`, you will have to debug that yourself, as it is not related to your question.